# Configuration file gives me values kind of randomely

Tags: java, bukkit

I am making a Minecraft Bukkit Plugin, and I have an issue with my configuration file.

When I try to get values from the configuration, with `getConfig().getString(path)`, it works perfectly. But now, I am trying to load a list of teams from my config, in YAML, they are:

```
teams:
    list:
      - ArnyminerZ
    ArnyminerZ:
      players: []
      prefix: ''
      suffix: ''
      dispname: ArnyminerZ
      seeinvbuddies: false
      friendlyfire: false
      color: WHITE
```

At first, I was using `for(String team : config.createSection("teams").getKeys(false))`, and it worked, but suddently, after some modifications, it stopped working, and I changed my method to loading a string list, and I don't know why, it works kind of strange.

In my `onEnable()` method, I have this:

```
public FileConfiguration config;

public static AlcoasUHC plugin;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    plugin = this;

    config = this.getConfig();
    loadConfigDefaults();

    getLogger().info("Alcoas UHC -> Enabled! There are " + scoreboard.getTeams().size() + " teams registered.");
}
```

And in an external class, I have the method `getTeams()`:

```
public List<String> getTeams() {
    return plugin.config.getStringList("teams.list");
}
```

The `loadConfigDefaults()` method simply loads some predefined values to the configuration, with `config.addDefault(path, value);` and `config.options().copyDefaults(false);`.

In this first method, the loading works ok, it debugs `Alcoas UHC -> Enabled! There are 1 teams registered.`. But when I try to load the teams again, for example, in this method:

```
} else if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("teams")) {
    List<String> teams = scoreboard.getTeams();
    if (teams.size() <= 0) {
        SendMessage.sendMessage(sender, 
     config.getString("messages.anyTeamCreated"));
    } else {
        StringBuilder printingTeams = new StringBuilder();
        for (String team : scoreboard.getTeams()) {
            if (teams.toString().equals("")) {
                printingTeams.append(AndColor.GOLD).append(team);
            } else {
                printingTeams.append(AndColor.GREEN).append(", ").append(AndColor.GOLD).append(team);
            }
        }
        SendMessage.sendMessage(sender, config.getString("messages.availableTeams").replace("%at%", printingTeams));
    }
}
```

It returns me an empty list in the server log, and in the game it runs this line `config.getString("messages.anyTeamCreated"));`, meaning that the list is empty.

What can I do? Am I doing something wrong?

I am using as Server `git-Spigot-549c1fa-45c8386`, Implementing API version `1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT`, with Minecraft 1.12.2, and I am programming with

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.3942.27, built on December 11, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: OK. I'm going to try it

Comment: OK that worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @Squiddie can you write this as an answer so this question can be marked as answered and closed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posted by the request of [bn4t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8392636/bn4t) to give [Arnyminer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5717211/arnyminer-z) a chance to accept the answer and solve this question publicly.*

According to Bukkit's API for [ConfigurationSection](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html) the method `createSection(String path)` has this description: *"Any value that was previously set at this path will be overwritten."*
This means when you execute that method, it will actually clean the section containing your teams as it will be overwritten, resulting in no teams being loaded.

What you want to use is `getConfigurationSection(String path)`, this will return the proper section if it exists. This doesn't override anything.

Or you could use a mixture of both of them. If `getConfigurationSection(String path)` returns null (if the section doesn't exist at all), create a new one using `createSection(String path)`. Like this:

`ConfigurationSection section = getConfigurationSection("your.path.here");
 if(section == null) {
     section = createSection("your.path.here");
 }`

Also this doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but I highly recommend loading the teams from the config only when it's necessary, like when server starts for example, instead of every time you're using it.